# Do we ever actually reason from induction?

Tags: induction

The sun has risen every day for many years. It would be unwise to bet on it not rising tomorrow. But is this because it has risen every day, or because there is nothing to suggest anything would be different? If induction was really playing a role in this decision to bet, wouldn’t we more confident the more days go by with the sun rising? I doubt that this is the case.

Would a person who has seen the sun rise for 100 straight days be any less confident than the sun rising for 1,000,000 straight days?

On the other hand, if there was some information indicating that the sun is about to collapse soon, the confidence one would have in the sun rising tomorrow would diminish. But this wouldn’t be based on induction. It would just be based on new information.

When do we actually use induction for any decision? When we bet that Messi will be the best player this year, is it because he played well for so many years, or is it because we have evidence that he can play well and has played at tiptop shape at some relatively recent point in history? Where is induction directly used to make any sort of bet or seemingly rational decision?

Comment: Our "expectation" are not based on induction: they are based on habits (maybe natural, i.e. hardwired into our brain).

Comment: Induction is the base of statistical inference: we survey many similar events (maybe we discard the "exceptional" ones) and we assume some sort of general law or rule governing/describing the events.

Comment: Yes, a person who has seen the sun rise for 100 straight days would be less confident than the person who has seen it rise for 1 million days. The difference between 1/100 failure chance and 1/1000000 failure chance matters a lot to insurance agencies, medical equipment manufacturers, airbag manufacturers, hard drive manufacturers, etc., and the best way to measure such chances is to observe actual failure rates in practice over 100 or 1 million cases.

Comment: But also it's wrong to draw a distinction between "induction" and "incorporating new information." Induction includes a lot more than just looking at past statistics for one kind of event. Any time you incorporate new empirical evidence you're doing induction.

Comment: In general a philosophical question, in particular a metaphysical one.  It isn't possible to formulate a simple sentence that could convey what we all seek, either in and of itself or, preferably, with a cherry on top. For now suffice it to say that we're unable to derive a critical conclusion that could close the case for some of the more interesting members of our species.

Comment: The aztecs, although they had no more reason than us to think the sun wouldn't rise made massive human sacrifice to make sure it would.

Comment: Discarding some exceptional cases, my computer programs have no bugs. But I feel better, the longer it's been since I noticed them running.

Comment: @ScottRowe "my computer programs have no bugs" lol, sure.

Answer (score 1):

We do indeed reason from induction. Like by understanding that the [principle of least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle) can be extracted from well known cases, and then be used very generally in unknown cases.

It is thought many pagan peoples felt appropriate sacrifices and rituals had to be made to bring summer back, and stop the days getting shorter. And that illustrates the point, it is about what your paradigm is, your frame of reference. If you lived in Sacandinavia and knew people that visited the Arctic circle, you would know sometimes in some places, the Sun does *not* rise, and you would seek ways to explain that using what you know, like a battle between the powers of winter and of summer. It's about modes of explanation, of reasoning. Focusing on physical evidence likely seems very obvious to you, but it's pretty new in human culture not to immediately reach for spiritual forces in the face of unknown circumstances.

Comment: That Insurance policy on the sun requires some sacrifices. But going without insurance is foolish. For the principle of least action, I think the explanation is that the universe is lazy.